# Navigation Component + Dynamic Feature Delivery

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

Is there any way we can test the Dynamic Feature delivery added on Jetpack Navigation component 2.3.0 locally via Android Studio? I am seeing that the only way to test right now is to upload the apk to internal app sharing on play console and test which one is more time consuming.

Comment: You're right. The only option is to upload your *.abb file to Google Play.

Comment: Yes, the problem is if developer uploads the new application to console, the review process takes up to 7 days. The developers has to wait for this duration to test the functionality. It is kind of blocker for developers.

Comment: You can use custom channels or internal channel. Review process of these is much shorter – couple of hours from my experience.

Comment: I am using internal channel and waiting on approval for last 3 days.